# v8::ScriptCompiler::Source object - can this be held on to or retrieved later?

Tags: c++, v8, embedded-v8

http://v8.paulfryzel.com/docs/master/classv8_1_1_script_compiler_1_1_source.html

I want to be able to hold on to the source code and `ScriptOrigin` data, but `v8::ScriptCompiler::Source` has `v8::Local` data members, so it would seem that you can't make a `v8::Global` out of it, as all the `Local` members would be invalidated as soon as the `HandleScope` went away.

So is there some way to get this information back from a `Script` or `UnboundScript`?

Or do I need to keep it around in my own structured format as well as creating a `v8::ScriptCompiler::Source` object?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

According to the mailing list, the answer is pretty much "no".

Comment: Hey, what's this project you're working on involving v8?

Comment: a c++ game engine scriptable via javascript.   Part of it is released as a standalone integration library: https://github.com/xaxxon/v8toolkit